# C++ QList const correctness

Tags: c++, qt, constants, const-correctness, qlist

I would like to fill in a `QList<double>` with `const double` values.

These `const double` are returned by a method which i am not to change.

How to do it simply ?

Comment: There's a method returning a `const double` by value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the values are being copied, it doesn't matter whether the function returns them as `const` or not.

Comment: there is compile errror however if i try to `myqlist.append(d)` where `d` is (const) double value returned by method.

Comment: To diagnose this, more information and context is required. What is the signature of the function returning the `double`, what does the code look like when you're calling the the `QList::append` function? A minimally (not) working example would be best.

Comment: @daramarak However, i have this error `error C3892: 'minmax' : you cannot assign to a variable that is const`